# Cassandra read performance degrade as we increase data on nodes

Tags: cassandra

- DB used: Datastax cassandra community 3.0.9
- Cluster: 3 x (8core 15GB    AWS c4.2xlarge) with 300GB io1 with    3000iops.
- Write consistency:      Quorum , read consistency: ONE    Replication
  factor: 3

Problem: 
I loaded our servers with 50,000 users and each user had 1000 records initially and after sometime, 20 more records were added to each users. I wanted to fetch the 20 additional records that were added later(Query : `select * from table where userID='xyz' and timestamp > 123`) here user_id and timestamp are part of primary key. It worked fine when I had only 50,000 users. But as soon as I added another 20GB of dummy data, the performance for same query i.e. fetch 20 additional records for 50,000 users dropped significantly. Read performance is getting degraded with increase in data. As far as I have read, this should not have happened as keys get cached and additional data should not matter.

what could be possible cause for this? CPU and RAM utilisation is negligible and I cant find out what is causing the query time to increase.
I have tried changing compaction strategy to "`LeveledCompaction`" but that didn't work either.

**EDIT 1**

[image: output for dstat command]

**EDIT 2**
Heap size is 8GB. The 20GB data is added in a way similar to the way in which the initial 4GB data was added (the 50k userIDs) and this was done to simulate real world scenario. "userID" and "timestamp" for the 20GB data is different and is generated randomly. Scenario is that I have 50k userIDs with 1020 rows where 1000 rows were added first and then additional 20 rows were added after some timestamp, I am fetching these 20 messages. It works fine if only 50k userIDs are present but once I have more userIDs (additional 20GB) and I try to fetch those same 20 messages (for initial 50k userIDs), the performance degrades.
[image: JMX output]

**EDIT 3**
[cassandra.yaml](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=05325836506460857975&t=0532583650646085797599568)

Comment: What is the size of your original data, before you add extra 20 GB of dummy data?

Comment: @Edmon: 4.2GB was present before adding 20GB dummy data.

Comment: Check this article. It might help you. I think your single node is overloaded: http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.com/2012/09/cassandra-read-performance.html

Comment: @Edmon: My partition key distributes data on all 3 nodes in cluster. So that possibility is ruled out. Also, read throughput if fine when I read with 4.2GB data but drops when I add 20GB data. My question is, what has that 20GB dummy dta got to do with read performance? I have userID and timestamp as primary key and the keys are cached.

Comment: @AtmeshMishra RF=3 means all 3 nodes get the same data, your data is replicated 3 times. If you want to spread your data among your cluster you'd use RF=1. The fact that key are cached means only you save one IOPS (and you have SSD so that's not a problem at all BTW). Your data is not cached and must be read instead.

Comment: @xmas79: True, what I meant was one node is not getting overloaded and all 3 nodes have equal load. Rows cannot be cached in my use-case as I will read new data everytime. Let me put my question in very simple sentence -- Why is 20GB data causing trouble in reading same data which worked fine earlier and how do I fix it?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra I suppose the (obvious) answer to your question is "because you add more data in a way that causes troubles", so the real question is "why adding data *in that way*, *with this configuration*, *with this model* cause a huge slowdown? Please update your question your table schema, and your C* configuration (eg Java Heap, Memtable memory configuration etc..). Without this *no-one* can answer.

Comment: @xmas79: I have updated my question with cassandra.yaml file along with jmx screenshot taken while running the query. I have also explained my problem.

Comment: @xmas79: Do you need some more information?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra I don't any reason why your data should cause these showdowns in this query. It would be useful if you'd post the table definition, and let's check the number of SSTables. As I already said, machine is reading a lot from disk. This is very suspicious to me. Unless you "accidentally" write in the same partitions over and over this should never happen.

Comment: @xmas79: I notices that cassandra was not using heap memory, instead it was eating up free RAM. Once I increased the RAM on machine from 16GB to 32GB, the performance improved and I could see around 10GB used as offf-heap cache. Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra consuming non-heap memory is good.consuming all heap memory can be bad.having very large heap is definitely bad due to stop-of-the-world GC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143898/discussion-between-atmesh-mishra-and-xmas79).

Comment: @xmas79: with 200GB data, 50GB off heap memory was being used. Now the point here is that I don't need cache and I have disabled cache, so why is it saving data on RAM? Also, I am reading only 4.2GB of data out of 200GB, why is it caching 50GB? also I have iops available on disk, I can afford to read from disk, why is it not using it?

Answer (score 1):

> Read performance is getting degraded with increase in data.

This should only happen when your add a lot of records in the same partition.

From what I can understand your table may looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    userID text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, timestamp)
);
```

This model is good enough when the volume of the data in a single partition is "bound" (eg you have at most 10k rows in a single partition). The reason is that the `coordinator` gets a lot of pressure when dealing with "unbound" queries (that's why very large partitions are a big no-no).

That "rule" can be easily overlooked and the net result is an overall slowdown, and this could be simply explained as this: C* needs to read more and more data (and it will all be read from one node only) to satisfy your query, keeping busy the coordinator, and slowing down the entire cluster. Data grow usually means slow query response, and after a certain threshold the infamous read timeout error.

That being told, it would be interesting to see if your DISK usage is "normal" or something is wrong. Give it a shot with `dstat -lrvn` to monitor your servers.

A final tip: depending on how many fields you are querying with `SELECT *` and on the amount of retrieved data, being served by an SSD may be not a big deal because you won't exploit the IOPS of your SSDs. In such cases, preferring an ordinary HDD could lower the costs of the solution, and you wouldn't incur into any penalty.

Comment: You got the table right. For each userId, there are no more than 1200 records, i.e. data per partition is bounded in this case. I am fetching no more than 8 fields per query. I have attached screenshot of dstat output in question.

Comment: @AtmeshMishra The screenshot shows the machine is constantly reading data at around 110MB/s. Did you take the screenshot during the query or was the machine idle (from your point of view)? The machine probably ran out of IOPS or throughput.

Comment: I took the screenshot while running the query as a part of loadtest. As mentioned above, I have disk with 3000 iops and aws-cloudwatch shows max 1100-1400 read Ops/sec. BTW, I had the same thought so I edited iops to 15000 (maximum for 300GB disk) result was still the same. The question here is, why is additional data affecting read performance?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra  Can you show us the query you use to insert this dummy data? Show us also some dummy data values. BTW, in this case if it's not the IOPS, it's the throughput IMHO.

Comment: I used "insert into tbl (userID, text, timestamp) values(?,?). I used random userID, text and timestamp to populate data. Also, I just realized that the table you figured is wrong, userID is part of PK and not text.